# show a CircularIndicator when loading more items in the flutter (pagination)

Tags: flutter, pagination

I have this code, it should return a circular indicator if the number of posts is more than the index number in the list, but it doesn't work. And not show me the indicator?

```
  BlocConsumer<PostsBloc, PostsStates>(
          listener: (context, state){
           
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if(state is PostLoadingState) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            } else if(state is PostLoadedState) {
               final posts = state.posts;
              return ListView.builder(
                controller: context.read<PostsBloc>().controller,
                itemCount: state is PostLoadingState
                    ? posts.length + 1 : posts.length ,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if(index < posts.length) {
                    final post = posts[index];
                    return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text("${index + 1}"),),
                          title: Text(post['author'].toString()),
                          subtitle: Text(post['title']['rendered']),
                        )
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                  }
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
```

post_bloc:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_events.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_repo.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_states.dart';

class PostsBloc extends Bloc<PostEvents, PostsStates> {
  PostRepo repo;

  int page = 1;

  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  PostsBloc(this.repo) : super(PostInitState(null)){
    controller.addListener(() {
      add(LoadMore());
    });

    on<FetchPosts>((event, emit) async{
      emit(PostLoadingState(null));
      final posts = await repo.fetchPosts(page);
      emit(PostLoadedState(posts: posts));
    });

    on<LoadMore>((event, emit) async{
      if (controller.position.pixels ==
          controller.position.maxScrollExtent && state is! PostLoadingState) {
        page++;
        final posts = await repo.fetchPosts(page);
        emit(PostLoadedState(posts: [...state.posts, ...posts]));
      } else {
        print("not called");
      }
    });
  }

}
```

and post_state:

```
abstract class PostsStates {
  final posts;
  PostsStates(this.posts);
}

class PostInitState extends PostsStates {
  PostInitState(super.posts);
}

class PostLoadingState extends PostsStates {
  PostLoadingState(super.posts);
}


class PostLoadedState extends PostsStates {
  PostLoadedState({required posts}) : super (posts);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more snippets, especially the BlocBuilder above the ListView.builder, the PostsBloc's class and the PostsState's class?

Comment: i have edited the question and added everything